# Python creating multiple threads and creating processing time

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am getting an error when I run my code:
"threads can only be started once"

it has to do with my `for I in range(10)`

I kill the threads right after I start it so in theory all threads should be killed before going back into the next loop to create another set of threads.

What I am trying to do is to get the time it takes to run a thread

```
def __startThreads__(self):
        print("How Many =", self.howMany)
        start1 = time()
        for i in range(10):
            start2 = time()
            for i in range(self.howMany):
                self.threads.append( ThreadEntity( str(i), iAmTheProgramCode ) )
            for each in self.threads: 
                each.start()
            for each in self.threads:
                each.killThreadEntity()
            stop2 = time()
            threadtime = stop2 - start2
            print(threadtime)
        stop1 = time()
        threadTotalTime = stop1 - start1
        print(threadTotalTime)
```

Comment: Next time, please format your code appropriately ;-) I fixed that for you, basically it was missing an indent.

Comment: How do you know it has to do with the line: 'for I in range(10)'?

Comment: if I put for I in range(1) it doesn't have a problem because it only tries 1 iteration of the loop but when I increase it to 2 it crashes

Comment: Here is the error I get:

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\cslaptop\Desktop\SimpleVirtualShell.py", line 133, in __startThreads__
    each.start()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 836, in start
    raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't start a thread after you killed it.

you iterate over `self.threads` 10 times (`for i in range(10)`).
and in each iteration you start all the threads in it (and append some new ones but you also iterate over the previous which were killed).

I think that what you ment to do is to empty the threads list before each iteration.

try add the next line after `for i in range(10)`:

```
self.threads = []
```